# Why Android Studio Preview has jumped from Android Studio 3.2 beta 3 to 3.3 Canary 1?

Tags: android-studio

I wonder why Android Studio Preview has jumped from Android Studio 3.2 beta 3 to 3.3 Canary 1. Shouldn't Android Studio 3.2 Stable be released and then 3.3 Canary, beta, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't Android Studio 3.2 Stable be released and then 3.3 Canary, beta, and so on?

No. Canary, by definition, is bleeding edge latest build. In this case, this means that they are ready to start version 3.3 while 3.2 is being finalized. 3.2 will bake for a bit longer in Beta form until they've ironed out any remaining issues, then be promoted to Stable.

But really, what difference does it make? Canary is newer than Beta is newer than Stable. The numbers assigned to any build is ultimately pretty arbitrary.